# Como verificar as informações do meu servidor de email

Tags: gmail

Como faço para verificar as informações do meu g-mail por exemplo portas servidor de entrada e de saída host etc. pois entrando em configurações eu não acho essas informações eu utilizo domínio próprio xxxxxx@agenciafront.com.br   existe alguma documentação que mostre onde consigo essas informações

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=pt-BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servidor de recebimento de e-mails (IMAP)
imap.gmail.com

Requer SSL: Sim

Porta: 993

Servidor de envio de e-mails (SMTP) 
smtp.gmail.com

Requer SSL: Sim

Requer TLS: Sim (se disponível)

Requer autenticação: Sim

Porta para SSL: 465

Porta para TLS/STARTTLS: 587

Nome completo ou Nome de exibição   Seu nome
Nome da conta, Nome do usuário ou Endereço de e-mail    Seu endereço de e-mail completo
Senha   Sua senha do Gmail
Fonte: [Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636305586282466717-1797488039&rd=1)